# How to round a number after adding so that unnecessary numbers are avoided

Tags: java

I have the following situation, when I give e.g. one number 10.55000, this number is rounded correctly to 10.55, then after adding 10.5501, everything is also fine because I get 21.1001, but in the next stage, when I add the number 10.55 I get the following result: 31.6501000001, and I should receive 31.6501. What should I do to get in stage 3 of 31.6501 instead of 31.6501000001.

This is my Numbers class:

```
class Numbers {

    private double result;
    private double currentNumber;

    public void calculateResult (double number) {

        currentNumber = number;
        result += currentNumber ;
    }

    public String getResult() {

        DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.##########");
        decimalFormat.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.CEILING);

        return decimalFormat.format(result);
    }
}
```

This is my main method:

```
    Numbers numbers = new Numbers();

    numbers.calculateResult(10.55000);
    System.out.println(numbers.getResult());

    numbers.calculateResult(10.5501);
    System.out.println(numbers.getResult());

    numbers.calculateResult(10.55);
    System.out.println(numbers.getResult());
```

Comment: You have to decide the scale and precision for your double number. Did you try BigDecimals?

Comment: Note that 10.55000 is not "rounded" to 10.55 - it's basically the same value with just a different representation (of course `BigDecimal` makes a distinction but from a mathematical point of view both are the same).

Comment: Related: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Thank you, Kris, that solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

As already stated floating point numbers such as `float` and `double` suffer from precision issues and those can add up with each calculation. For more exact calculations you should use `BigDecimal` instead.

Here's an example of your class that keeps the same method signatures but uses `BigDecimal` internally:

```
class Numbers {
  private BigDecimal result = BigDecimal.ZERO;
  private BigDecimal currentNumber;

  public void calculateResult( double number ) {
    currentNumber = BigDecimal.valueOf( number );
    result = result.add( currentNumber );
  }

  public String getResult() {
    //no rounding here because your question doesn't involve any actual rounding
    return result.toString();
  }
}
```

Output for your test calculations:

```
10.55
21.1001
31.6501
```

Note that the example above doesn't actually do any rounding, i.e. if you add `0.000001` then this will get reflected in the resulting value.

If you need to round to let's say 4 significant decimal places (0 to 4 at most) you could use this instead:

```
return result.setScale( 4, RoundingMode.CEILING ).stripTrailingZeros().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You must set your format appropriately. Use `new DecimalFormat("#.####")` instead of `new DecimalFormat("#.##########")` because you only want to see 4 digits after the dot.

This will give you

```
10,55
21,1001
31,6502
```

If you need higher precision you need to use a different data type for example `BigDecimal`

Comment: This does not solve my problem because it is not a universal mechanism, because if I enter a number e.g. 85.55017, it will cut off the number 7

Comment: "If you need higher precision ..." note that even with less fraction digits there might be precision errors when using floating point numbers.

Comment: @UnknownBoy  The `7` is not cut off. The value is rounded to `85,5502`. That's the result I would expect from rounding. As mentioned, if you need precise results without rounding you cannot use `double` values as they are inherently imprecise.